# How to catch when input type='date' is cleared?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to catch when my date input is cleared to "MM/DD/YYYY". I don't want my input to ever be "MM/DD/YYYY". How can I catch that and change its value when it is cleared? My function looks something like this and it doesn't seem to work.

```
   handleChange = event => {
        if(isNaN(event.target.value)){
         event.target.value = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY");
         return;
        }
         this.setState({date: event.target.value});
        }
```

Comment: You're fighting the native browser user agent styling here, maybe a better idea is use a datepicker plugin instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the native HTML input element of type `date`?

```
<input type="date" />
```

If yes, an empty input (`'MM/DD/YYYY'`) is simply interpreted as an empty string`''`.

First, we have to maintain the date state within the component, and the input value will be mapped to the value of `date`. Then, at the `onChange` event, if the input value is an empty string, you can reset the date to today's date in the `if` statement by updating the state using `setState()`, and updating the value with today's date.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: ""
    };
  }
  onChange = e => {
    const date = e.currentTarget.value;
    if (date === "") {
      this.setState({
        date: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        date
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { date } = this.state;

    return <input type="date" value={date} onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} />;
  }
}
```

I have created a demo over [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-meninsky-sr53e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: I am getting an error that says that the value is NaN and that if I'm expecting it, I should set it to be a string. I don't think I would pass your if statement because my value isn't ' ', its NaN.

Comment: It was actually a change handler. It is fired onChange.

Comment: `Warning: Received NaN for the 'children' attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.`

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to call `moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY");` is the date input is empty?

Comment: Because I want the value to be set to today's date when the input is cleared.

Comment: Oh ok I get what you need now. Also, you are using a class component, not functional component, right?

Comment: Yes. It's a class based component.

Comment: @DavidNogueira i have updated my code. Added a demo too

Comment: Yes! I am sorry for the long wait. I had this issue on the back burner for a little while. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <input type='date'onchange="myFunction(event)"/> 

  <script>
    function myFunction(event) {
      if(event.target.value ==''){
              // You can write your code here.
              // console.log(event.target.value);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

works fine on chrome